# continue the pipeline job eventhough one stage is failed

Tags: jenkins

This is thew pipeline script i am using

```
def map = [FRA1: "192.168.1.1", DEL: "192.168.1.2", NYC: "192.168.1.3"]
map.each { key, value ->
    echo "${key} ${value}"
    stage("job test-${key}"){           
       build job: 'jobcheck', parameters: [string(name: 'DC-NAME',value: "${value}")] 
        
       
    }
}
```

Now , suppose one of the stage is failed pipeline job is ending . i need to continue to next stage even previous one is failure.
i have tried with propagate:false value. but in that case it is moving to next job but marking success for all the stages. i still want to see them as failure

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [catchError](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure) keyword for achieving exactly what you want, it will catch the exception (when build fails) and will set the stage result and the build result to which option you want.
for example:

```
def map = [FRA1: "192.168.1.1", DEL: "192.168.1.2", NYC: "192.168.1.3"]
map.collectEntries {key, value ->
    ["Running ${key} ${value}" : {
        stage("Triggering another job- ${key}") {
            catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                build job: 'testjobcheck', parameters: [string(name: 'DC-NAME', value: value)]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked neatly. how ever I do have one more followup question will post in another thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172384/running-jenkins-job-in-parallel-from-pipeline-job